# Print out on paper is different from print preview in crystal report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I have designed a crystal report and used A4 paper size by default. When I run a preview of my crystal report then all the fields' contents show on the correct location on the page but when I make a printout, then all the fields' contents do not print at their proper locations. The printout does not match with my crystal report preview. I am using Crystal Report with Visual Studio 2010. Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these steps :

1, in crystalreportviewer, if you click print, go to flag LAYOUT, and set CENTER TO PAGE

2, in Crystal report application, go to PAGE SETUP (right click on page) and set all the margins to 5

let me know, if it help
nice day